# flutter socket.io client not working ~~~ helpme

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, socket.io

I am making a chat app using flutter.
However, the socket connection does not work.
Port 80 is all connected locally, but sockets using aws are not connected.
I've tried both http and https, but no response. Help me!

Only the app does not connect, but the web connects.
The version of socket io client is 1.0.2, and the version of socket io is 2.3.0.

```dart
class _WebrtcState extends State<Webrtc> {
  late final IO.Socket socket;

  // late final SocketIO socketIO;
  final _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  final _remoteRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  MediaStream? _localStream;
  RTCPeerConnection? pc;
  String check = "aafafasdfs";

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState');
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future init() async {
    print('init');
    await _localRenderer.initialize();
    await _remoteRenderer.initialize();
    await connectSocket();
    await joinRoom();
  }

  Future connectSocket() async {

      print('connectSocket');

      socket = IO.io('http://********', IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());

      print(socket.opts);

      socket.onConnect( (_){
        print('connect');
        setState(() {
          check = "11111111111111111111ㅈ111";
        });
      });

      socket.on('joined', (data) {
        _sendOffer();
      });

      socket.on('offer', (data) async{
        data = jsonDecode(data);
        await _getOffer(RTCSessionDescription(data['sdp'], data['type']));
        await _sendAnswer();
      });

      socket.on('answer', (data) {
        data = jsonDecode(data);

        _getAnswer(RTCSessionDescription(data['sdp'], data['type']));
      });

      socket.on('ice', (data) {
        data = jsonDecode(data);
        _getIce(RTCIceCandidate(data['candidate'], data['sdpMid'], data['sdpMLineIndex']));
      });




  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a WebSocket connection, we need to create a new WebSocket using the special protocol `ws` in the URL:

```dart
final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
  Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.org'),
);
```

There's also encrypted `wss:// protocol.` It's like HTTPS for WebSockets.

Please change the URL to something like the below form :

`ws://********`

`wss://********`